# Issue with shell script running on crontab \n doesnt work

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am working on a cron job, to check and recover ark files if required. I need to get the biggest file size of .ark files and if .TheIsland.ark file is smaller it will auto backup and copy over the biggest size. Now while I have this working out side of crontab one part of the script fails.

Which is:

```
actualmap=$(find $PWD -type f -printf '%p\n' -name "*.ark"| sort -nr | head -1)
```

If I remove the \n it actually works but then it cannot sort between them as it is not in separate lines.

The output I get on cron job with \n is:

```
/srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/recovery.sh (which is the recovery script)
```

The same line of code ran in terminal produces the correct output of:

```
/srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/SavedArks/TheIsland_NewLaunchBackup.bak
```

Without \n using crontab I get:

```
/srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/SavedArks/TheIsland_27.06.2019_21.46.20.ark/srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/SavedArks/TheIsland_28.06.2019_15.15.34.ark
```

I have attached full code which works manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0

##ARK Map Recovery Script
cd /srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/SavedArks

#Check file size of current ark map
file=TheIsland.ark
echo $file
currentsize=$(wc -c <"$file")
echo $currentsize

#Find biggest map file.
actualmap=$(find $PWD -type f -printf '%p\n' -name "*.ark"| sort -nr | head -1)>/srv/daemon-data/da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae/ShooterGame/Saved/SavedArks/log.txt
echo $PWD
echo $actualmap
biggestsize=$(wc -c < "$actualmap")
echo $biggestsize

if [ $currentsize -ge $biggestsize ]; then
    echo No map recovery required as over $biggestsize bytes
else
    echo Uh Oh! size is under $biggestsize bytes Attempting map recovery
    echo Checking for Backup dir and creating if necessary
    mkdir -p BackupFiles

    #Move old map into backup dir in the saved location
    echo Moving old Map File to backup dir
    mv $file BackupFiles

    #Stop server using docker commands
    echo Stopping servers

    docker kill da4aaa1b-0ce9-46d2-bd60-5f599cc089ae
    #Copy biggest map file with correct name
    echo Copying backup file
    cp $actualmap $file
fi
```

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/, fix all the issues, then if you still have a problem create a minimal script that JUST demonstrates THE PROBLEM and post that for help.

Comment: FYI: Indentation and empty lines to break up sections of code will make your script easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-printf` option to the `find` command is not required here.  `-print` will do just fine.

I obtain the result you want (find returning the found filenames, one per line) with this:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.ark" -print.
```

With `-printf`, `%p` gives you the filename anyway.

From `man find`: -print True; *print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a newline*.

Option `-print` already does what you want to do.